# How to handle modules in separate files

Tags: angularjs

I like it to have every controller, filter, ... in a saparate file. The Problem is, that I have to copy every path in my main html file.what ist a good pratice to automate this workflow? I found the grunt-concat module. But is this the way?

Another question is, when i have the different modules in the saparate files like:

```
function TestCtrl ($scope) {
 //...
}

angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl)
```

I have to add them to my app.js like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['add here?']);
```

Thank you very much!
Robert

Answer (score 2):

Grunt concat is a good way to concatenate your files.

And to answer your other question: the code would be:

```
var app = angular.module('loop', ['app'])
```

but probably you should rename the variable 'app' to 'loop', to avoid confusion with the dependency.

EDIT: added as additional answer to your question in your comment:

Yes, it also works with []. You defined a module by angular.module('name',[]) and the array contains dependencies if your module rely on them. If not, than you need to supply the empty array. Calling angular.module with two arguments is called the setter api to create a module. When you use angular.module('name') without the array, you get a reference to the created module. That is useful to define services, controllers and so on, like this:

```
angular.module('appname').controller('controllername'[function(){....}])
```

As last remark, you can chain both the getter and setter of the angular.module api and get rid of the (global) variable app altogether. Such as:

```
angular.module('appname',[])
  .controller('controllername'[function(){....}])
  .factory('factoryname', [function(){}])
```

Comment: what these "['app']" do? It also works with "[]"! Is there another way? I also found LazyLoad, is there a way to automate it? Or what about requirejs?

Comment: Sorry the loop was a copy and paste failure. I fixed it!

Comment: @nofear87, I added answers to the questions you asked in the comment above.

Comment: when i choose the first way to define...how the array must look like?

Comment: just an empty array: []

Comment: and how I define a dependecy? i havent understand when i have to fill the array I think :D Do you have an example for me, in which case dependencies makes sense? thank you!

Comment: you can depend on for instance ui.router for routing in your application. Check out the angular.ui website for a good example of using dependencies in your own project. Basically you can build upon that work. There are many more projects you might want to include, that saves you lots of work

Comment: ok, i understand, but why they are doing something like this: var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[ 'myApp.filters',...]) for example in this seed: https://github.com/robertjchristian/angular-enterprise-seed/blob/master/ui/js/app.js because they dont define them as module? is this a better way then my one?

Answer (score 0):

Concat and LazyLoad are two different concepts, right? Or can I use them together?What ist the difference between requirejs and lazyload?